# Javascript class member becomes empty in Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox

I have a class in JS with field

```
Widget = function ()
{
    this.Attributes = []; // key=value
}
```

and another class iherited from `Widget`

```
BusinessStatisticWidget = function ()
{
  // some code
};

BusinessStatisticWidget.prototype = new Widget();
```

At initialization stage I have assigned this Attributes field with values (only once) and at some point Atttibutes field becomes empty:

```
BusinessStatisticWidget.prototype.SetEventsOnControls = function ()
{
    var dropDown = document.getElementById(this.DropDownName + this.type + "Id");

    var _this = this; // **Not empty here**
    dropDown.addEventListener("change", function (event)
    {
            // **Not empty even here**
        _this.CalculateAndSetTimeRangeForTimeSpan(event.target.value);
    }, false);
}
BusinessStatisticWidget.prototype.CalculateAndSetTimeRangeForTimeSpan = function (val)
{

// **Empty here**
    if (this.Attributes["fromDate"].value != '' && this.Attributes["toDate"].value != '')
    {}
}
```

The code above works fine in Chrome and IE10 (I mean that array is not empty) but dont work in Firefox(20.0.1)

As array is empty I get `TypeError: this.Attributes.fromDate is undefined.` 
And I dont know why it is empty and how to fix this.

Comment: TypeError: this.Attributes.fromDate is undefined. Like I said - this.Attributes is empty, And I dont know why and how to fix this

Comment: There are several closing braces missing in your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple problems with your code:

1. Don't use arrays for arbitrary key, value pairs. Use only numerical keys for arrays.
2. Each instance will share the same `Attributes` array. This is usually not the desired behaviour.

Solutions:

1. Use an object instead.
2. Setup inheritance properly and call the parent constructor in the child constructor.

Code:

```
Widget = function () {
    this.Attributes = {}; // use an pbject
};


var BusinessStatisticWidget = function () {
  // call parent constructor
  Widget.call(this);
  // some code
};

// set up inheritance
BusinessStatisticWidget.prototype = Object.create(Widget.prototype);
```

More information (and polyfill) about [`Object.create`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create).

---

Now, I don't know if that fixes your problem, but it makes your code at least more correct so that finding the issue becomes easier. I recommend to [learn how to **debug** JavaScript](http://www.netmagazine.com/tutorials/javascript-debugging-beginners).